# tomcat SSL request parameters lost

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have a web-page, there are couple of text boxes and a submit button. On submit, the target url matches the url-pattern for SSL. The target page gets opened as HTTPS, but the textbox values are lost.

```
request.getParameter("txtUser") is null
```

Is there any way to access/retreive the submit/request parameters from previous jsp?

**web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
   <display-name>Security Constraint</display-name>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>          
      <url-pattern>/content/account/passrecover/*</url-pattern>          
   </web-resource-collection>               
      <role-name>custom-report-user</role-name>       
   <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
   </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean that your form is submitting to an HTTP url via POST, and then is automatically being redirected (per the transport-guarantee), to an HTTPS url?

Then no, I don't think there is any built-in support to save those parameters so that they persist after the redirect. Generally, you would want to make sure the form posted to an HTTPS url directly.

It is possible to implement a server-side mechanism, but it's not trivial to integrate transparently with the servlet API. Spring Security has some built-in handling and classes for it. (I think one of the key classes in recent versions is [RequestCache](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/RequestCache.html), but not positive.)

Comment: Thx. How can I make the form post to HTTPS? The URL is actually relative, so the hyperlink is like /content/account/passrecover/index.jsp, I don't think it can be changed to something like https: //www .website.com/abc/content/account/passrecover/index.jsp

Comment: You will need to make the form's submit URL absolute somehow. It would only work as a relative URL if your current page is already on HTTPS protocol.  There are multiple ways to do so. 1) Store the absolute HTTPS URL base as a configuration variable.  2) Dynamically calculate the HTTPS URL on the server, perhaps using ServletRequest.getRequestURL().  3) Use JavaScript to calculate the HTTPS URL based on current page's URL and then modify the form's submit action.  The dynamic options can be difficult to implement in a reusable manner if you also need to support ports beyond 80 & 443.